# deleting entity causes ObjectDeletedException in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, mapping

I am trying to map cascading relations between 3 entities in hibernate.The entities are

```
1.Item --has a Maker and a Distributor.
2.Maker --has a set of items created by him.
3.Distributor ---has a set of items he distributes.
```

Relations needed:

```
1.When an Item is saved/updated ,its Maker and Distributor should be saved/updated
2.When a Maker is deleted ,all his items should be deleted.
3.When a Distributor is deleted,all his items should be deleted.
```

I tried like this,

```
class Item{
    private Long item_id;
    ...
    private Maker maker;
    private Distributor distributor;
    ...
}
Item.hbm.xml
...
   <!--
    when Item is saved the associated Distributor is also saved
    -->
   <many-to-one name="distributor" class="Distributor" column="DISTRIBUTOR_ID" lazy="false" cascade="save-update"/>
    <!--
    when Item is saved the associated Maker is also saved
    -->
    <many-to-one name="maker" class="Maker" column="MAKER_ID" lazy="false" cascade="save-update"/>
...

class Maker{
    private Long maker_id;
    ...
    Set<Item> items;
    public Maker(){
        items = new HashSet<Item>();
    }
...
}
Maker.hbm.xml
...
<!--
when a Maker is saved,all his items are saved.
when a Maker is deleted,all his items are deleted.
-->
<set name="items" inverse="true" table="ITEM" lazy="false"  cascade="all,delete-orphan">
            <key column="MAKER_ID" />
            <one-to-many class="Item" />
</set>
...


class Distributor{
    private Long distributor_id;
    ...
    Set<Item> items;
    public Distributor(){
        items = new HashSet<Item>();
    }
    ...
}

Distributor.hbm.xml
<!--when a Distributor is saved, all his items are saved.
    when a Distributor is deleted, all his items are deleted
-->
<set name="items" inverse="true" table="ITEM" lazy="false" cascade="all,delete-orphan">
<key column="DISTRIBUTOR_ID" />
<one-to-many class="Item" />
</set>
...
```

Then I created some instances and tried to find out if deleting a Maker deletes all his items..
However,when I try this,I get this error

```
hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [myapp.domain.Item#27]
```

I think ,it is because the Set items belongs to both Maker and Distributor.I am not sure how to model/map this properly..
Can someone help me out?I am really taking my first lessons with hibernate.

sincerely

Jim.

```
main(..){
  createEntities();
  deleteSomeEntities();
}

public void createEntities(){
   session = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
   Transaction tx = null;

   Maker maker1 = new Maker();
   maker1.setName("maker1");

   Distributor dis1 = new Distributor();
   dis1.setName("dis1");

   Item item1 = new Item();
   item1.setName("item1");
   item1.setMaker(maker1);
   item1.setDistributor(dis1);

   Item item2 = new Item();
   item2.setName("item2");
   item2.setMaker(maker1);
   item2.setDistributor(dis1);

   Set<Item> items = new HashSet<Item>();
   items.add(item1);
   items.add(item2);
   maker1.setItems(items);
   dis1.setItems(items);
   try{
        itemdao.saveOrUpdate(item1);
        itemdao.saveOrUpdate(item2);

    }catch(RuntimeException e){
        logger.error("rolling back"+e.getMessage());
        tx.rollback();
        throw e;
    }
}

public void deleteSomeEntities(){
    session = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try{
        Maker maker = makerdao.findMakerByName("maker1");
        String name = maker.getName();
        logger.info("got maker:"+name);
        makerdao.deleteMaker(maker);
        tx.commit();
    }catch(RuntimeException e){
        logger.info("rolling back");
        tx.rollback();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whenever you get this error, its because you are trying to delete an object, but that object is referenced in some parent objects list, and your transitive-persistence (i.e. cascade) settings are set such that the parent controls the relationship.  In other words, you are giving hibernate conflicting commands: you are telling it to delete the object, but you are also telling it that if the object is in the specified collection, do a save.

Just remove the object you are trying to delete from the collection in the parent, or change your cascade/inverse mappings.

Comment: That means I will have to clear items from two parents,Maker and Distributor..will try..thanks

Comment: @jimgardener, yep.  Or change your cascade settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find it's the cascade on your mappings.

cascade="save-update"

try cascade="all" and then Hibernate should do it for you.